# Azure Functions V3: Unable to get ILogger working with DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, azure-functions, serilog

We have an Azure Function v3 and would like to inject an `ILogger<MyFunction> logger` into our function classes via constructor. We are struggling to get it to work with Serilog as the default logger.

I have tried different ways as shown below with different errors.

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(sp =>
        {
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Elasticsearch(
                new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(...)
                .CreateLogger();
            return new SerilogLoggerProvider(logger, dispose: true);
        });
    }
}
```

However, I get following error:

> Method Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton: type argument 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TImplementation'.
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

If I try to add the factory like following:
`builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(sp => new LoggerFactory());`

The error is:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: Registered factory delegate returns service Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory is not assignable to container.
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Trying to add the logger into a provider into a factory in one go when adding the IFactoryLogger results in following error:

> Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider>)'.
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

I've also tried to add the default logging without declaring a factory:

```
builder.Services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Describe(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>), ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
```

The error is:

> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'factory').

Am I missing something crucial here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the way to add Serilog in Azure Functions V3:

- Create an instance the Serilog logger, with all the configuration for console and file sinks.
- Register this logger in the `builder.Services.AddLogging` method.

**Related Code:**

```
// Startup.cs - Registering a third party logging provider
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
builder.Services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(logger));
```

**Complete Startup.cs:**

```
// Startup.cs
using AzureFunctionDependencyInjection.Configurations;
using AzureFunctionDependencyInjection.Services;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Serilog;
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(AzureFunctionDependencyInjection.Startup))]
namespace AzureFunctionDependencyInjection
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // Registering Configurations (IOptions pattern)
            builder
                .Services
                .AddOptions<MessageResponderConfiguration>()
                .Configure<IConfiguration>((messageResponderSettings, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration
                    .GetSection("MessageResponder")
                    .Bind(messageResponderSettings);
                });
// Registering Serilog provider
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
            builder.Services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(logger));
// Registering services
            builder
                .Services
                .AddSingleton<IMessageResponderService, MessageResponderService>();
        }
    }
}
```

Check out this detailed and great article: [Dependency Injection in Azure Functions V3](https://medium.com/@therealjordanlee/dependency-injection-in-azure-functions-v3-7148d0574dfc) on this.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, very helpful addition. I've managed to fix my specific issues by adding the package "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" as I only had "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" referenced.